# How to enable local ~ autocompletion for scp?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete, scp

**Too late: The machine, OS and configuration in question is no longer in use, so I can't verify any more suggestions. I have not encountered this problem in Fedora or Arch Linux. If *you* are having this problem, please post another question with the details of your configuration.**

Whenever I want to copy a file from my home directory, I run into this issue: `scp` won't autocomplete paths preceded by `~` (tilde). This is very simple to verify by typing `scp ~/` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice - No file completions are shown. Even if I specify a unique path prefix such as `scp ~/.bash_hist` it won't complete. Is this by design, configurable, or a bug?

To clarify, all other parts of the completion work: host names and paths on remote hosts both complete just fine. Completions of paths with tilde also work with other commands, such as `ls`.

Could there be some restriction on completing a non-standard `~`? Mine points to `/home/users/username` and is an NFS 3 mount to another host (`/home/username` is used for speed-critical things like the browser profile). I have not changed `$HOME` (`/home/users/username`) or some other craziness.

On Fedora 19 it works - <kbd>Tab</kbd> completing `scp ~/foo` results in it *replacing* the `~` with `/home/username` and subsequently completing normally.

**Please note**: This question is **neither** about autocompleting as root **nor** autocompleting remotely. Bash completion is installed an working fine.

Running openssh-client 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1 and GNU bash version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: on my system `scp ~/` followed by two tabs expands `~/` by `$HOME` and show me all valid candidates for autocompletion. I use `bash` version 4.1.5. Probably you have a custom completion enabled for `scp` so `~` isn't examined by your shell anylonger.

Comment: Question would be nice for autocompleting on the host :)

Comment: @user1146332 Tested on two Ubuntu 12.04 hosts without any custom completion that I know of, and it gets the same result. Which platform/version are you using?

Comment: i'm working with debian lenny.

Comment: @warl0ck If there is no `hostname:` before the `~`, it is unambiguously on localhost. That should be easy to take into account in the autocompletion code.

Comment: @l0b0 oh, I thought he wants to complete the files on remote machine.

Comment: It works here on Ubuntu 12.04. @Bernhard: also completion on the host works.

Answer (score 1):

When working under Debian Lenny, do this:

```
apt-get install bash-completion
```

Then go for ~/.bash_profile to enable it locally or /etc/profile to add it system-wide. Paste the following in:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
 . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Any reference to why it would have to be enabled for all users to work for *a single command* for a normal user?

Comment: If it's one user, just go for the .bash_profile. Leave /etc/profile out. More on the profile files here: [http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html)

Answer (score 0):

bash `auto-completion` seems to be the way to go.
install the `bash-completion` package.

And then in `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` there are references to `scp` command.

Comment: Bash completion is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (for what it's worth, on OS X 10.11, stock bash 3.2.57, bash-completion 1.3 via brew).  Following [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/27485157#27485157) I expanded the tilde in the ssh completion file (`/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` in my case, or `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` otherwise) as follows:

```
_scp_local_files()
{
    local IFS=$'\n'

    local dirsonly=false
    if [ "$1" = -d ]; then
        dirsonly=true
        shift
    fi

    cur="${cur/#\~/$HOME}" # <<< Expand tilde

    if $dirsonly ; then
        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
            sed -e "s/$_scp_path_esc/\\\\&/g" -e '/[^\/]$/d' -e "s/^/$1/") )
    else
        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
            sed -e "s/$_scp_path_esc/\\\\&/g" -e 's/[*@|=]$//g' \
            -e 's/[^\/]$/& /g' -e "s/^/$1/") )
    fi

    COMPREPLY="${COMPREPLY/#$HOME/~}" # <<< Contract tilde
```

I also found it nice to contract back the tilde at the end, keeps paths nice and short (as originally typed anyway).